# Error on persisting same entity twice within a transaction

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

Consider an Entity that exists in the db.
The following actions occur within a transaction -

```
mainfuntion()
{
    transaction.begin();
    function1();
    if(check some business logic )
    {
        function2()
    }
    transaction.commit()
}
function1()
{
    query1 - returns Entity
    modify Entity;
    EntityManager.persist(Entity)
}
function2()
{
    query1 - returns Entity
    modify Entity
    EntityManager.persist(Entity)
}
```

Now the two modifications that occur make sense to be kept logically apart hence I do not want to club the two modifications. I would also prefer not to pass along the Entity between the two methods.

On commit i get the following exception -

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve the desired result without the error?

Comment: In function 2 you merge the entity and not persist it again

Comment: Tried, merging it if already exist in persistence context. Does not work. :(

Comment: @LaurentiuL. it makes business sense to do both or none.

Comment: what is the error while merging it?

Comment: same error.. 
Just to confirm, you are suggesting to do something like -
if(Entity exists in persistense context) - EntityManager.merge(Entity)
else - EntityManager.persist(Entity) 
right ?

Comment: one more thing is your entity changes in function2? why if else? it is being handled by the JPA persistenceContext it self

Comment: Further more how are you creating the "id" of the entity?

Comment: you mean to say Hibernate strategy is being used to generate ids, right?

Comment: @BilboBaggins I am assigning keys myself.

Comment: Hmmmm try using the hibernate strategy... :) :) :)

Comment: can you post your code on github? and provide the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the `@Version` annotation with Date/Timestamp in your entity?
I have encountered a similar situation in the past. Hibernate while trying to update Entities with an `@Version` column, includes the `@Version` column along with the primary key in the update statement.

hibernate docs mention this -

> When using a java.util.Date, instead of a long/Long for the revision
>   timestamp, take care not to store it to a column data type which will
>   loose precision.

This results in the second update statement not fetching the desired row and hence the unexpected row count exception.

Try it without the `@Version` annotation or with integer/long version.